# downloading the google play services

Tags: google-play-services

This app won't run without google play services, which are missing from your phone. it's asking me for a code for redeem, setting and or _________   please help me reinstall the google play services that was on the phone it an LG trac phone through page plus

Answer (score 0):

Try intalling Google play services from play store. If play store is not working without  it, try to download Google Play Services from external sites. There are many mirrors available on internet. Once done, try rebooting your device. This must solve the problem if some app requires google play services to be installed.